# Cannot reference records two levels lower with delegated_type directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I designed the following model using STI in a Rails (Rails 7.0.8, Ruby 3.2.2) app.

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  delegated_type :fooable, types: %w[Bar]
end
```

```
module Fooable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :foo, as: :fooable, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  include Foobale

  delegated_type :fooable, types: %w[Bar Buzz]
end
```

```
module Barable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :bar, as: :barable, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

```
class Piyo < ApplicationRecord
  include Barable
end
```

1. I want to get all records whose `barable_type` is Piyo among the Bars that are related to a certain User's record via Foo.
2. I want to be able to narrow down Bars based on Piyo's ID.

I tried using Array-related methods because ActiveRecord's search method cannot be used in this case.

### 1

```
bars = user.foos.bars.includes(:fooable).select do |foo|
  foo.fooable.barable_type == 'Piyo'
end

bars.map(&:fooable) # Array of Bar
```

### 2

```
bar = user.foos.bars.find(proc { raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound }) do |foo|
  foo.fooable.barable_type == 'Piyo' && foo.fooable.barable_id == id
end

bar.fooable # Bar
```